# ArangoDB for each distinct push other element to an array

Tags: arangodb

So I have a collection in ArangoDB where subnets are assigned to teams and I would like to re-format that data to have a single line per team with an array of their assigned subnets

The collection (Assigment) looks like this:

**Query**

```
FOR a IN Assigment
    RETURN a
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "assignment_type": "subnet",
    "assigment_crteria": "192.168.1.0/24",
    "team_assignment": "Team1",
    "prime_contact": "John",
  },
  {
    "assignment_type": "subnet",
    "assigment_crteria": "192.168.2.0/24",
    "team_assignment": "Team1",
    "prime_contact": "John",
  },
  {
    "assignment_type": "subnet",
    "assigment_crteria": "192.168.3.0/24",
    "team_assignment": "Team1",
    "prime_contact": "John",
  },
  {
    "assignment_type": "subnet",
    "assigment_crteria": "192.168.4.0/24",
    "team_assignment": "Team2",
    "prime_contact": "Bob",
  },
  {
    "assignment_type": "subnet",
    "assigment_crteria": "192.168.5.0/24",
    "team_assignment": "Team2",
    "prime_contact": "Bob",
  },
  {
    "assignment_type": "subnet",
    "assigment_crteria": "192.168.8.0/24",
    "team_assignment": "Team5",
    "prime_contact": "Anna",
  },
  {
    "assignment_type": "subnet",
    "assigment_crteria": "192.168.9.0/24",
    "team_assignment": "Team2",
    "prime_contact": "Bob",
  },
  {
    "assignment_type": "subnet",
    "assigment_crteria": "192.168.10.0/24",
    "team_assignment": "Team2",
    "prime_contact": "Bob",
  },
  {
    "assignment_type": "subnet",
    "assigment_crteria": "192.168.12.0/24",
    "team_assignment": "Team5",
    "prime_contact": "Anna",
  },
  {
    "assignment_type": "subnet",
    "assigment_crteria": "192.168.13.0/24",
    "team_assignment": "Team1",
    "prime_contact": "John",
  },
  {
    "assignment_type": "subnet",
    "assigment_crteria": "192.168.15.0/24",
    "team_assignment": "Team1",
    "prime_contact": "John",
  },
  {
    "assignment_type": "subnet",
    "assigment_crteria": "192.168.17.0/24",
    "team_assignment": "Team7",
    "prime_contact": "Erick",
  }
]
```

And I would like to insert the re-formated documents in a different collection (Team_to_Subnet) with this format:

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "team": "Team1",
    "cidrs": ["192.168.1.0/24","192.168.2.0/24","192.168.3.0/24","192.168.13.0/24","192.168.15.0/24"],
    "prime_contact": "John"
  },
  {
    "team": "Team2",
    "cidrs": ["192.168.4.0/24","192.168.5.0/24","192.168.9.0/24","192.168.10.0/24"],
    "prime_contact": "Bob"
  },
  {
    "team": "Team5",
    "cidrs": ["192.168.8.0/24","192.168.12.0/24"],
    "prime_contact": "Anna"
  },
  {
    "team": "Team7",
    "cidrs": ["192.168.17.0/24"],
    "prime_contact": "Erick"
  },
]
```

How would I go about doing this? Is it even possible to do it? I've looked into using COLLECT but I just cant figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by team and contact with `COLLECT`, and use a [projection expression](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-collect.html#discarding-obsolete-variables) to get an array of subsets that fall into the respective group:

```
FOR a IN Assigment
  COLLECT team = a.team_assignment, prime_contact = a.prime_contact
  INTO cidrs = a.assigment_crteria
  RETURN { team, prime_contact, cidrs }
```

To save the results, just replace the last line with:

```
  INSERT { team, prime_contact, cidrs } INTO Team_to_Subnet
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that does exactly what I needed. Much apprciated.